# Exactly how many characters fit into windowed console windows in both x64 and x32?

Tags: windows, windows-console

This is a common problem I run into since I test on 64 bit then have to have the code work on 32 bit machines on windows 7.

A lot of times I pay no mind to how much character length I use -- but on my machine I get way more characters per line, so I never really know for sure if my code will display properly on the other machines until I try it.

I really need a better method than guess n check -- I'm pretty sure there are only 80 characters on the console window in 32 bit, but I wasn't sure if that was only in full-screen mode, or if you still got that many while it was windowed.

I know its probably a silly question. But right now I'm operating under the assumption that up to 80 characters fit on a single line in the console window for 32bit windows.

Comment: It's user-definable and doesn't really depend on bitness

Comment: [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo) will tell you both the size of the scrollback buffer, and how much of that buffer fits in the window.

Comment: You can have a thousand characters in a line with a 32-bit machine or 10 with a 64-bit machine. It has nothing to do with the processor type.

Comment: its not really important at this point, since Ben Voigt's solution works... but even though it has nothing to do with the processor type itself, by default on windows 7 32 bit the console definitely fits less than the same os on 64bit... and sometimes you cannot control the machines you have to run it on. So many times I had to make last minute changes to ascii art tables lol.